# Changing already created text fields into currency fields?

Tags: custom-field, currency

So I have a really tedious problem. I've been plopped into a SalesForce setup that was created by someone else and they want me to automate our company's billing process a little. The issue is for some reason the guy that set everything up created all of our pricing fields as text fields. I changed them all in my testing environment, but I know that if I were to try to do that in our live pages it would just delete all the values we have stored for every record with that field. Is there any way to directly change these text fields into currency fields? Or possibly to export all the data and then import it back without too much trouble?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: I would of opted for doing it in 3 steps: 1 - create the currency fields, 2 - copy all the values from the text field into the currency field, 3 - delete the text fields

Comment: Is it possible to automate the copying? We have 80+ records with ~15 fields each that need to be converted. The text is in the same format as it would look in a currency field, but that also means that it contains a euro symbol as part of the field, whereas our currency fields add in the euro symbol automatically.

Comment: Yes you could create a [batchable class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) that would select all the objects and copy the data over, removing the "$" symbol if needed.